# Pattern Matching callbacks for inputs of a form on multiple pages

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a use case where I am rendering a form with multiple select dropdowns. The form can be rendered with varying numbers of selects (chosen from a file). I am using dashboard_bootstrap_forms for this. I am rendering each form with a unique ID and there can be multiple number of such forms on a page in different tabs. The users can decide how many tabs to open and each tab has this form.

Form example

```
dbc.Form(
  id={“type”: form, “index”: 1}, children=[list_of_selects]
)
```

Select example

```
dbc.Select(
  key=key
  id={“type”: “select”, “index”: 1},
  options=options,
  size=“sm”,
)
```

Whenever I submit the form I want to access the info of all the selects in that particular form.
I am doing it with the STATE

```
@callback(
Output(toaster, “is_open”),
[Input(form, “n_submit”)],
[State({“type”: “select”, “index”: ALL}, “value”)],
[State({“type”: “select”, “index”: ALL}, “key”)],)
```

As you can see I am using the index: ALL to get data from all the selects.
The issue is it returns all the selects in all the forms along with the one that is submitted. I was thinking of pattern matching on a particular form ID, but from the documentation, I couldn’t find how to do that as the form IDs are generated dynamically and are not available when the callback is registered.

What would be the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try using [MATCH](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks#simple-example-with-match) instead of ALL?

Comment: I can't use `MATCH` because I want to capture the state of a bunch of select inputs, basically all present in a particular form.

Comment: Then Match on the selected form so your callback has the State of all the children of that form and parse through that data to get what you want. Also you can try posting to https://community.plotly.com/. They have good feedback too.

Comment: Also, it's still a little confusing what you're going for here. Consider elaborating your question and give some examples of what's currently coming into your callback and what you want coming into it.